# Replacing time stamp with time counter

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, matplotlib-widget

So, I have created a tracking system that responds to clicks on an image (using matplotlib). When the user clicks, it returns the coordinates of the point and the current time. (I am exporting this to csv using pandas). The time is included because I am plotting the output in a time-series graph. This is where the issue comes in.

I spend about 3 hours tracking this data, but only 1 hour of this tracking is active tracking time. There are many stoppages and starts (much like a basketball game), but the amount of time between the stoppages is variable.

Currently, I am returning the time using: self.time datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"). Then I adjust the times in an excel spreadsheet. I am hoping to replace this with a time counter (starting at 0) that starts and stops with a radio button (as a part of matplotlib widgets).

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As you want a radio button, 
you need first a GUI (https://docs.python.org/2/faq/gui.html)

Please choose one of them:  Tkinter, wxWidgets, Qt, Gtk+, FLTK, FOX, OpenGL

(when choosing you may also need to have a consideration in the OS you use in your project : Windows, OSX or Linux)